# How do i deal with HP Device Manager requiring authentication to remove print jobs?

Tags: printing, authentication

I have Fedora 20, with Gnome 3 Classic, and have installed Okular to read and, especially, print pages from, .pdf files. I want to print only a few pages, but in my frustrated attempts to set this up I have created, unintentionally, two print jobs that start printing the whole document each time I turn the printer on. the only ways I know to stop wasting ink and paper are to switch the printer off or take the paper out of the feed tray. Any attempt to print anything at all just starts these jobs off again.

If I try to use HP Printer Driver Manager to "Reject" (i.e. remove or delete) the print job I get a window saying that "authentication is required", but no combination of Username and Password that I know of will work, and there is a small twirly "please wait" or "working" symbol that prevents me from closing the HP Printer Driver Manager window, and never goes away. The only way I know of to get out of this is "shutdown" in the command line to turn the computer off.

Obviously I am missing something, possibly obvious, beyond my comprehension. Please can anyone help me out of this impasse, even by using different software?

Comment: This might be related to the HP manager. Please see if you have CUPS installed, for example browse to https://localhost:631/ and see if you can do something there.

Comment: I tried that site, localhost:631, but got a severe message warning that it was unsafe. `yum install cups` says it is already installed and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I can cancel the jobs with `lprm`:

```
   [1533][Harry@localhost:~]$ lpq   
    HP-LaserJet-Professional-P-1102w is ready and printing   
    Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size   
    active  Harry   13      /home/Harry/Domestic/5750201829 513024 bytes   
    1st     Harry   14      201_829_K                       207872 bytes   
    2nd     Harry   15      (stdin)                         0 bytes  
    [1533][Harry@localhost:~]$ lprm 13   
    lprm: Job #13 is already canceled - can't cancel.   
    [1912][Harry@localhost:~]$ lprm 14   
    [1912][Harry@localhost:~]$ lprm 15   
    [1912][Harry@localhost:~]$ lpq   
    HP-LaserJet-Professional-P-1102w is ready and printing   
    no entries   
    [1912][Harry@localhost:~]$
```